# What is the difference of callback and module exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is an article I've seen about the callbacks in javascript. https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced I know that I can understand it by reading the article. However, I'm getting confused of the callback while studying the module export in `node.js`

Callback - `A callback is a function that is to be executed after another function has finished executing`

Callback in `javascript`

```
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
  console.log(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
  callback();
}

doHomework('math', function() {
  console.log('Finished my homework');
});
```

Module export in `node.js`

//app.js

```
const logger = require('./logger');

logger.log(10, 10);
```

//logger.js

```
const multiply = require('./multiplication');

function log(valueOne, valueTwo) {
  multiply('The result is ', valueOne, valueTwo);
}

module.exports.log = log;
```

//

```
function multiply(speech, valueOne, valueTwo) {
  let result = valueOne * valueTwo;

  return console.log(speech + result);
}

module.exports = multiply;
```

and ran the `node app.js` on my terminal.

The result that I got from running the `node app.js` is `The result is 100` and that is correct.

But my question is 
`Does the approach that I did on the node app is consider as callback as well?`

Comment: *"Callback - A callback is a function that is to be executed after another function has finished executing"* That is just a completely incorrect definition of "callback." Unless that definition had major caveats on it, I wouldn't continue to use whatever resource you got that from.

Comment: No, there is no callback in your node app. Which function would you consider to be a callback?

Comment: A callback is a function that you pass to another function to be *called back* when the function finished doing a certain task.  You do not pass any function to another function in your code.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

> Callback - A callback is a function that is to be executed after another function has finished executing

That's not a correct definition of "callback." Unless that definition had major caveats on it you didn't quote, I wouldn't continue to use whatever resource you got that from.

A fairly broad definition of a callback is:

- A callback is a function you pass to something else (as a function argument, property value, etc.) that the other thing will call when its defined criteria for calling the function are met.

Some might argue for a narrower definition:

- A callback is a function you pass to another function for that other function to call back when its defined criteria for doing so are met.

Examples of callbacks:

1. DOM event handlers, although we usually call them "handlers" rather than callbacks. (Broad definition.)
2. The function you pass to `Array.prototype.sort` to compare array elements. (Both the broad and narrower definitions.)
3. The function you pass to `new Promise` to start the asynchronous operation the promise will observe (called the "promise executor function"). (Both the broad and narrower definitions.)
4. The function you pass to `Array.prototype.map` to transform elements. (Both the broad and narrower definitions.)
5. The function you pass to a promise's `then`, `catch`, or `finally` method.
6. The function you pass to `fs.openFile` that Node.js will call when the file has been opened (or the operation has failed). (Both the broad and narrower definitions.)

...and many others.

Notice that many of those (2, 3, and 4) are called *before* the function calling them has finished executing.

> Does the approach that I did on the node app is consider as callback as well?

No. Although you use `multiply` in `log`, it's just a function you call from `log`, not a callback. This would be a callback:

```js
function multiply(a, b, cb) {
    cb(a * b);
}
function showResult(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}

multiply(7, 6, showResult);
```

`showResult` is used as a callback when calling `multiply`.

Comment: Thank you so much for a one detailed answer, It helped me a lot! :)

Comment: Now I know that module exports is not a callback. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely understand your question. However, from what I gather, `module.exports` does not make a function a callback function explicitly. The purpose of `module.exports` is to allow access to that function when requiring the relevant `.js` file...as seen in your example.

Your `log()` function is a not a callback as you are simply passing in parameters and then using those values to call the `multiply` function and output the result.

When you call the `multiply` function you are simply calling it like so:

`multiply('some text', 10, 10)`

For this to be a callback it would have to take a function as it's final parameter, i.e.:

```
multiply('some text', 10, 10, function(err, data) {
    // ...
})
```

This also goes for the `log` function, and any for that matter. 
So, unless the final parameter of a function is a function, it is a not a callback. `module.exports` purely allows access to that function or the functions you specify in the object, for example:

```
module.exports = {
functionOne: someFunctionName,
functionTwo,
functionThree
}
```

If the name of the function is the same name as what you are trying to export you do not need to specify a value to the key.

Comment: May I know which part of the question that you don't understand?